# Cannot install ITKR package on OS X (Yosemite)

Tags: r

I have installed `oro.nifti`, `fslr`, `cmaker`, and then tried to install `ITKR`, but getting the following error message:

```
cmake: command not found  
Error: Command failed (1)  
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ITKR’
```

I have installed CMake software in case that was required! I was following a [post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/white-matter-segmentation-in-r/) from r-bloggers.com.
I am using R 3.2.2 in Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite).

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to install ANTsR from the OSX binary:
https://github.com/stnava/ANTsR/releases/
Here is a direct link to the OSX binary: https://github.com/stnava/ANTsR/releases/download/v0.3.1/ANTsR_OSX_Binary_Package_0.3.1.tgz

If you want to still to try to build from source, then you may want to check `cmake` is in your `PATH`.

To see if `cmake` is in your `PATH` variable.

- Open up `Terminal` either using Spotlight or `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` and then type:
  `which cmake`

  If there is no return line, then you should investigate your `PATH` variable (which may be quite long):
  `echo $PATH`

To add the cmake path to your `PATH` variable, open `~/.bashrc` or `~.bash_profile` using a text editor (try `open ~/.bashrc` in `Terminal`):

- If you have installed CMake by building it from source: 
  I believe by default the path for `cmake` is `/usr/local/bin` so add the line `CMAKE_PATH=/usr/local/bin;
  export PATH=$PATH:$CMAKE_PATH;`

  to this file.
- If you downloaded the binary (.dmg file and drag/dropped CMake into /Applications):
  then add
  `CMAKE_PATH=/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/;
  export PATH=$PATH:$CMAKE_PATH;`

  to this file.

Try and rerun.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that Rbloggers post.